# How do I calculate the expected value of a random walk with drift that includes (log)normal and a "rare-disaster/" two-point distribution?

Tags: self-study, distributions, expected-value

I'm working through an old qualifying exam, and part of a problem requires finding $E_t[X_{t+1}^{1 - \alpha}]$, where $X_{t+1}$ follows a random walk with drift that includes an iid normally-distributed shock and an iid "rare-disaster" shock that follows a two-point distribution. The process is defined as

\begin{equation}
\ln(X_{t+1}) = \ln(X_{t}) + \delta + \epsilon_{t+1} + \eta_{t+1}
\end{equation}

where $\epsilon_{t+1} \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and

\begin{equation}
\eta_{t+1} \sim
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{with probability } e^{-\lambda} \\
-m & \text{with probability } 1 - e^{-\lambda}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

The parameters $\alpha, \delta, \sigma, \lambda$, and $m$ are all positive constants. My first attempt was
\begin{align}
\ln(X_{t+1}) &= \ln(X_{t}) + \delta + \epsilon_{t+1} + \eta_{t+1} \\
X_{t+1} &= X_{t} e^\delta e^{\epsilon_{t+1}} e^{\eta_{t+1}} \\
X_{t+1}^{1 - \alpha} &= X_{t}^{1-\alpha} \left[ e^\delta e^{\epsilon_{t+1}} e^{\eta_{t+1}}\right]^{1 - \alpha} \\
E_t[X_{t+1}^{1 - \alpha}] &= E_t[X_{t}^{1-\alpha}] E_t[e^{\delta(1 - \alpha)}] E[(e^{\epsilon_{t+1}})^{1-\alpha}] E[(e^{\eta_{t+1}})^{1 - \alpha}]
\\
&= X_{t}^{1-\alpha} e^{\delta(1 - \alpha)} E[(e^{\epsilon_{t+1}})^{1-\alpha}] E[(e^{\eta_{t+1}})^{1 - \alpha}]
\\
&= X_{t}^{1-\alpha} e^{\delta(1 - \alpha)} e^{(1 - \alpha)^2 \sigma^2 / 2} E[(e^{\eta_{t+1}})^{1 - \alpha}] & e^{\epsilon_{t+1}} \sim \ln N(0, \sigma^2)
\end{align}

This is where I got stuck. The essence of the problem is that I don't know how to calculate
\begin{equation}
E[(e^{\eta_{t+1}})^{1 - \alpha}]
\end{equation}
In general, I *think* that
\begin{equation}
E[\eta^{1-\alpha}] = \Pr(\eta = -m) (-m)^{1 - \alpha} + \Pr(\eta = 0) 0^{1 - \alpha} = (1 - e^{-\lambda}) (-m)^{1 - \alpha}
\end{equation}
I omit the time subscript because $\eta$ is iid. I'm not sure how, or if, that helps me calculate $E[(e^{\eta_{t+1}})^{1 - \alpha}]$ though.

Am I on the right track? Is there another (standard) method for calculating the moment(s) of such a distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E[(e^{\eta_{t+1}})^{1 - \alpha}]=E[(e^{\eta_{t+1}{(1 - \alpha})})]$

Now $\eta_{t+1}(1 - \alpha) $ is a variable of the same form as $\eta_{t+1}$ but with a different value of $m$.

Note  that $e^\eta$ is still a two point distribution. Its expectation is *simple* to calculate.

Comment: Right, so I'm calculating the expectation of exp(two-point distribution), which is where I got stuck. It looks somewhat like a moment-generating function, but I'm unsure.

Comment: See edit to my answer.